# Can't connect to laptop webserver after tethering to android phone

Tags: android, apache, tether

Searched several threads and I'm still having issues.  I've tethered my laptop to my mobile phone and I'm using the data on it.  I checked the IP address assigned to my laptop and made sure I'm using it, set up the apache webserver to listen on a port (no IP specified).  And I can't connect from my mobile phone to my laptop web server.

Using localhost in laptop web browser works but it won't work if I use the IP specified by the android device after I tether.  Also can't connect to laptop webserver from phone's mobile browser either.

Why can't I connect to my local webserver on my laptop from my mobile phone?

I've tethered both with USB and mobile hotspot and successfully shared the internet connection, but using ipconfig from the command prompt in windows I never can connect using that IP http://:3128/ 3128 is the port I have apache listening on (because I had IIS before too).  Never works.

Comment: `it won't work if I use the IP specified by the android device after I tether`. Indeed. You should use the ip of the laptop.

Comment: `I've tethered my laptop to my mobile phone`. ??? Unclear. Who is thethering now? What is the hot spot?

Comment: For the first comment you misunderstood, what I meant was that when I'm connected I use ipconfig to get the laptop's IP address.  In different scenarios the ip comes from the router or the android device, that's what I meant.  So I always use the IP of the laptop when trying to connect to the laptop.  For the second comment I am always connecting my android phone to my laptop, either the phone creates a mobile hotspot and my laptop connects OR I use USB tethering and connect my phone to my laptop...always connecting laptop to phone it's just different where the internet comes from...

Comment: Solved it by no longer bothering, moved web service to a public online reachable location and pointed my mobile device there.